# QT XML reader reads the same tag everytime

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, qt, readfile

I try to read an XML file and the reader reads it well, until it reads one specific tag (the close tag of **Categories**) and afterwards it read this tag infinite times.

This is the xml file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <MovieMain MovieName="movie1" Version="1.29746.011215">
           <FrameGroups FirstFrame="START" LastFrame="END">
              <GroupFramesDescription>ALL MOVIE</GroupFramesDescription>
                 <frames Framenumber="1" >
                    <ObjectsGroup Name="1">
                       <LeftUpCorner X="30" Y="124" Z="0" />
                       <RightDownCorner X="53" Y="160" Z="0" />
                       <InfoAtt AttName="INDEX" AttInfo="1" />
                       <Categories>
                          <Category Name="computer" Probability="0.79"  />
                          <Category Name="pen" Probability="0.7"  />
                          <Category Name="desktop" Probability="0.1"  />
                          <Category Name="mug" Probability="0.09"  />
                       </categories>
                    </ObjectsGroup>        
                 </frames>
              </FrameGroups>
              </MarkingChanges>
                 <ChangesList UserName="ooo" Date="12/3/2015" ChangesetIndex="1" />
              </MarkingChanges>
          </MovieMain>
```

And this is the function that I call to read the next element:

```
orXmlReader->readNextStartElement();
```

It gives me every time the next element till the close tag of **Categories** and than it read it again and again (I tried a loop of 100 times...).

I hope that you will help me as soon as you can,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening tag is `<Categories>` and closing is `</categories>` , i believe that search is case sensitive. Can you try with `</Categories>` as closing tag?

Comment: I didn't make a search. but maybe the **readNextStartElement** function checks if it's a good tag or not.